# Force Git to show a delete + move to deleted path as a delete + rename rather than edit + delete

Tags: git

This is perhaps the opposite of the usual question: I *want* Git to do rename detection more aggressively than it actually does.

```
$ git init demo
Initialized empty Git repository in …/demo/.git/
$ cd demo
$ echo '#include b' > a
$ (for x in {00..99}; do echo $x; done) > b
$ git add a b
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) …] initial
 2 files changed, 101 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 a
 create mode 100644 b
$ git rm a
rm 'a'
$ git mv b a
$ git commit -m inlined
[master …] inlined
 2 files changed, 100 insertions(+), 101 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 b
$ git show -p
commit … (HEAD -> master)
Author: …
Date:   …

    inlined

diff --git a a
index …..… 100644
--- a
+++ a
@@ -1 +1,100 @@
-#include b
+00
+01
+02
+03
+04
+05
…
+95
+96
+97
+98
+99
diff --git b b
deleted file mode 100644
index …..0000000
--- b
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,100 +0,0 @@
-00
-01
-02
-03
-04
-05
…
-95
-96
-97
-98
-99
```

Is there some way to display this change as what I intended—a deletion of `a` combined with a move from `b` to `a`—but as an atomic commit, since the intermediate state is invalid?

In particular I care about how this would be presented by GitHub for purposes of code review.

A bit more generally, I may be editing the big file slightly after the move (a small proportion of its lines), and I would want the diff to display just those edits on top of the move, as Git would do automatically if it did not happen to be renamed to a file path which had previously existed. As it is, the real edits would get lost in the noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no: Git's (and GitHub's) rename detection is based on the file name in the left-side commit being not-found-at-all in the right-side commit, and some file in the right-side commit being not-found-at-all in the left-side commit.

That is, if we have this:

```
left        right
-----       -----
fileA       fileA
fileB
            fileC
fileD       fileD
```

then the only rename candidates are *<left=fileB>* and *<right=fileC>*.  Files *<left=fileA, right=fileA>* have been deemed to be "the same file" (paired-up, or "identified" as a verb<sup>1</sup>) *because* they have the same pathname, and similarly files *<left=fileD, right=fileD>* have been identified by name, leaving only B and C un-paired.

When you run `git diff` (or `git show` or anything that invokes `git diff` internally) manually, you can add the `-B` option, which allows you to "break" a pre-declared pathname-based pairing if the files are sufficiently dissimilar.<sup>2</sup>  So on the *command line*, you could perhaps achieve what you want.  But GitHub do not offer you the `-B` option.

---

<sup>1</sup>That is, Git is, at this point, concerned with the metaphysics problem of *identity*.  See [the Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus).  Is version X of some file "the same file" as version Y of that file?  How do we know?

<sup>2</sup>The `-B` option takes two numbers, both of which are ultimately expressed as a similarity index percentage.  Initial name-based pairings are first tentatively broken into separate "delete old left-side file" and "add new right-side file" if the similarity index of the two files' content falls below a threshold.  They then become candidates for rename detection, provided `-M` is enabled (perhaps via `diff.renames`, which is now default true instead of default false).  If rename detection does not take away one or both of the pair, they will be rejoined unless the similarity index falls below a second—usually more-lenient—threshold.

The `-B` numeric arguments are expressed in terms of *dis*-similarity rather than similarity, but the dissimilarity of version X of file F vs version Y of file F is simply 100 minus the similarity.

Comment: Nicely explained, thank you. Indeed `-B` is the trick which makes this work from a manual diff.